# What does clogging mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am buying a moisturizer cream for the pores on my face. I saw the below description for the product:

> Moisturizes, nourishes, removes wrinkles, renews and protects your face **without clogging your pores**.

Doesn't it help for my pores?

I saw the meaning of clogging in Google but am unable to construct the sentence.

If it doesn't help to cover my pores then I am not willing to buy it.

Comment: Have you checked what _pores_ are? It sounds as if you misunderstand the word.

Comment: What did the dictionary say when you looked up "clog" and "pore"?

Answer (score 2):

Google's definition is "block or become blocked with an accumulation of thick matter."  It is almost always a bad thing to happen.

When skin pores become blocked, then spots and pimples can develop.

This just says "it won't clog your pores".  Moisturiser is not meant to cover your pores. It is not makeup. Makeup can clog your pores, which is why you should remove your makeup at night.